# Event mesh messaging cloud sdk for java does not work as expected

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I want to use this library https://api.sap.com/api/SAPEventMeshDefaultMessagingAPIs/cloud-sdk/Java to post messages to my queue.

What have I tried so far:
Removed OneOf keywords as per documentation
Generation of the library failed but the artifacts were created successfully

What failed:
Using SynchronousMessagingApi in particular this method queuesQueueNameMessagesPost to post messages to queue.

I have two issues with this api:

**First**, the content type 'any-content-type' is hardcoded and it always throws error if not uncommented.

`final String[] localVarContentTypes = {  "any-content-type" };`

in method `selectHeaderContentType it always picks the hardcoded content type 'any-content-type'`

**Second**, the method **queuesQueueNameMessagesPost** signature for payload is a java.io.File but event messaging does not file input.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of fixing the specification:

- The quickest option would be to edit the spec file to replace `any-content-type:` by `application/json:` or `text/plain:` on the broken variables and methods
- But you can also reach out to the [SAP Event Mesh team directly](https://answers.sap.com/tags/73554900100800000765) or use component id `BC-CP-EM-MES` if you have access to [service now](https://support.sap.com/en/index.html) and ask the team for a fix on the spec file.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up changing the spec file and it works without changing the code.